# How were binary subroutines embedded in Integer BASIC programs?

Tags: apple-ii, integer-basic

Programs written in Apple's Integer BASIC sometimes had bits of machine code embedded in them.  This was more convenient than loading the code separately, especially when the program was loaded from tape.

When the program is first loaded, it looks garbled.  For example, the classic APPLE-VISION demo starts like this:

```
    0 LOMEM:1800
    1 HIMEM:8192: POKE 202,165: POKE 203,27:LOMEM:6144:CLR : GOTO 0
 8264, RUN LOMEM:*2664439008, ^ , RUN , ? ABS *2664439008, ^ , RUN ABS *266438288; RUN ^ , RUN 6164,=58882/42004#2112 24576*
```

The `LIST` command would sometimes go into an infinite loop.  But after the program is first run, the listing looks more normal:

```
    0 REM  *** APPLE-VISION ***  WRITTEN BY R.J. BISHOP
   20 DIM A$(51)
   30 A$="       BOB BISHOP PRESENTS . . . APPLE-VISION!       "
   40 CALL -936
```

How does this work, in terms of both the underlying mechanism and the mechanics of developing a program that hides code this way?  e.g. how does one combine the BASIC and machine code portions before saving to disk or tape?

**Update 1:** for the curious, a commented disassembly of APPLE-VISION can be found [here](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-applevision/).

**Update 2:** another program by Bob Bishop, called Bomber, was written entirely in assembly language, but used an Integer BASIC wrapper.  As far as I can tell, this was done solely to make it easier to play the game from cassette tape: you could read it in with a `LOAD` command from BASIC, instead of having to drop into the monitor and specify an address range.  Full disassembly of Bomber is [here](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-bomber/).

Comment: I vaguely remember tricky stuff like you showed above, but for small machine-language subroutines, it was more straightforward to embed it as a sequence of decimal numbers in DATA statements, and a loop that POKEd them into memory.

Comment: @jameslarge: Integer BASIC didn't have DATA statements. It was written by Woz, not derived from Microsoft BASIC, so it has very different characteristics from what you find on other systems.

Comment: BTW, the same worked in Applesoft Basic: You could add machine code after the end of a basic program by fiddling with same memory locations, and it even wouldn't show up in the listing, but you could reliably `CALL` it.

Comment: From Apple's CONTACT magazine, MAY '78: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.apple2/0BRpraMdkDg/k4Getz6XDgAJ

Answer (score 10):

In [this Integer BASIC disassembly](http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/6502/INTLST.TXT), 202/203 ($CA/$CB) is `PP` - "ptr: start of program". It looks like they're changing the "start of program" location, then re-running it by doing a `GOTO 0`.

My guess is that there's a small BASIC program (the one you see at the start), then a chunk of assembly language that looks like junk when listed, then another small BASIC program (the one you see at the end).

What I'm not sure is why they don't just jump directly into the assembly routines… I might have to investigate further :-)

Assembly language *was* often included in BASIC programs though: although the [S. H. Lam Technique](http://www.llx.com/~nparker/a2/shlam.html) is for Applesoft BASIC, a slight variation works fine in Integer BASIC. It fills the keyboard buffer with keystrokes, then calls the monitor parse-and-process routine to execute the keystrokes as a monitor command.

```
10 DIM H$(23):H$="300:AD 30 C0 60 N D9C6G"
20 FOR X=1 TO LEN(H$): POKE 511+X, ASC(H$(X,X)): NEXT X
30 POKE 72,0: CALL -144
40 PRINT "HELLO"
50 END
```

Other programs found creative ways of embedding actual assembly code somehow into a BASIC program. Ivan Drucker's [KansasFest talk](https://youtu.be/QmRG-SVZHgc) on [Slammer](http://ivanx.com/appleii/slammer/) discusses a clever, modern variant of this technique.

Comment: (1) Link-only answers are discouraged... consider making this a comment instead. (2) Slammer appears to be for Applesoft BASIC, not Integer BASIC.

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer the question, but neither has anyone else. :-) APPLEVISION has a full hi-res character generator, so poking it in probably wouldn't be practical. +1 for providing code. (The down-vote wasn't from me.)

Answer (score 9):

Generally, this involves some very careful work, where you overwrite part of the tokenized BASIC program with the binary data, or add the binary data to the tokenized BASIC code while carefully adjusting the counters showing where things are located in the code. It's a tricky process and I never thought it was worth the trouble, given how easy it is to mess up.

It does make it harder to edit the BASIC code, since it becomes problematic for the BASIC interpreter to revise the code as you make changes when it can't understand the "tokenized code" which is actually binary data. That makes it a crude copy protection scheme both in terms of obfuscating the code and in terms of making it harder to change the code without damaging it.

I don't have the details on how to pull this off handy; it can be figured out by looking at the internal format of the tokenized BASIC code, though. Once you know how Integer BASIC (and Applesoft, for that matter) store their code, you can start to manipulate it to do pretty clever things. It takes patience and practice though.

Answer (score 8):

The technique that zellyn describes above for having the Monitor process a command from the input buffer was, as he said, devised for Applesoft. In fact, one of its crucial elements is specific to that language: the "D9C6G" references the Applesoft ROM code. As it happens, the file that was often distributed to provide Integer BASIC for the Language Card had, of course, Integer BASIC itself, plus the mini-assembler and Sweet-16 interpreter, at $E000 to $F7FF, with "Programmer's Aid #1" added at $D000 to $D7FF, and $D800 to $DFFF left with simply a copy of the Applesoft ROM code of the same address space. Thus, the routine at $D9C6 *was* present, and the above-listed technique would work. However, this would not be reliable -- the $D800-$DFFF space might not have a copy of that portion of Applesoft; and in particular, if the above is tried on an original-model Apple ][, with Integer BASIC itself in ROM and no trace of Applesoft, it definitely *won't* work. There is an address intrinsic to Integer BASIC that does the same job: E817. Use that in place of D9C6 for something that will reliably work.

A second, minor point is that the "N" just before the D9C6/E817 is used to safely terminate the memory-assignment command. That's usually fine, as it just sets text to "Normal" display mode. However, if one happened to have been using Inverse mode, this would cancel it. A completely generalized method would be to replace the "N" with a "<" directly prefixing the E817G: "<E817G".

More significantly, however, a faster technique for storing the string in the input buffer, compared to a BASIC poke-loop, would be to "trick" Apple's DOS 3.3 into storing the string in the input buffer for you, by PRINTing it as a simulated DOS command. (The bold-italic ***D*** is an embedded "ctrl-D"):


`10 PRINT "D 300:AD 30 C0 60 <E817G";:POKE 513,141:PRINT:
   POKE 49,0:POKE 52,2:CALL -123`


In the above line, the PRINT begins with a "ctrl-D" to indicate a DOS command. This causes DOS to store all that is printed in the input buffer, instead of actually printing it. The POKE 513,141 then replaces the second character, which was a SPACE, with a <Return> in the buffer. Then PRINT actually generates a <Return>, to let DOS process the "command". Thanks to the above POKE, DOS sees only a "null" command, and does nothing more. Then the two POKEs and CALL set up the monitor and have it process the printed string as a command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and welcome to the site. You might want to read the [tour] to get a feeling for how the site works.

Comment: Wow, fantastic. I didn't realize what ctrl-D did under the covers, but it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak directly to Apple Integer BASIC, but I know that TRS-80 BASIC programs could encode machine language in DATA statements (as in Leo Christopherson's [Android NIM](http://www.dnull.com/demon/)) or even in literal strings. A string containing machine code would include lots of non-printing characters that would do things like moving the cursor backward or up, or clearing the screen, so the listing would look garbled.

If the program shows up normally after it's run, that probably indicates that it's self-modifying; again, the Android NIM page above mentions this.

As for how to do it: You *could* write code in assembly language, run it through an assembler, and then insert the machine code into strings or data statements, but these machines were so small and simple that an ambitious programmer could compose machine code directly.

Comment: I once entered machine code directly, the Spectrum manual lists op-codes, their byte value, and the matching BASIC token side-by-side :)

Comment: Sinclair ZX-81 and ZX Spectrum BASIC programs often used the technique to store (even large) machine code portions in REM statements. (Actually, on the ZX-81 it was extremely common, as it was the absolutely most simple way to do it)

Comment: If I remember correctly, TRS-80 BASIC strings had a length byte followed by data, so you could store a maximum of 255 bytes of machine code in one string. I think a longer machine language program would be broken up into multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

Bob Bishop helped us with a Machine Control program using the Apple ][ as a Machine Controller with GREAT Graphics. Late '70 and early 80's
He showed me the trick where you insert the Machine Code in a REM Statement of the First line of basic, then modify the Line code to say it at the end. I forget the actual Tokens used.. I have them somewhere in a Stack of notes. The list will not show the Garbage as the list stopped looking at the line, and the Next Line Memory location Pointer showed the Start of the next printed line.  If the REM statement you have modified is the First line of the Program, and the First Line is just a REM Statement, then it's always in the same place in memory to execute a Call to.